# Why is my api response not inserted into postgres

Tags: python, postgresql

```
    dictionary = testEns(idSession)
    columns = dictionary.keys()
    for i in dictionary.values():
        sql2='''insert into PERSONS(person_id , person_name) VALUES{};'''.format(i)
     
        cursor.execute(sql2)
```

The function testEns(idSession) contains the result of an api call that returns an xml response that has been transformed into a dictionary.

i'm trying to insert the response into a table that have been created in a postgres database but here is the error i'm getting. Any idea why? and what am i missing?

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "{"
LINE1: ...nsert into PERSONS(person_id, person_name) VALUES{'category...
```

After I changed VALUES{id, name} to VALUES(id, name)

I have this error

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "id" does not exist
LINE 1: ...sert into PERSONS(person_id , person_name) VALUES(id, name)
```

eve though my table PERSONS is created in pgadmin with the columns id and name

Comment: Is `i` here and object with the person_id and person_name?

Comment: 1) You should be using proper [Parameter passing](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries). 2) It needs to be `VALUES ()`.

Comment: @HasaniH Yes i is an object that will contain each of the values inside the variable dictionary for each iteration.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver that's what I tried to do but It gives me an error saying that the columns does not exist even if these columns DOES exists in my data table

Comment: 1) We need to see  what `i` actually is? Add that to your question, 2) Also add the complete error message.

Comment: done! I hope it's clearer now thx

Comment: No it isn't.  1) If `persons` has columns `id` and `name` why are you trying to insert into `(person_id , person_name)`? 2) Where are `id` and `name` defined? 3) Last but not least, again what is `i` ?

Comment: 1) it was just to be clearer in my explanation but I know it is supposed to be id and name 2) i is used to take each values in a dictionary. for example: thisdict = {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "year": 1964
}
for x in thisdict.values():
  print(x)

Comment: The more you explain the less sense you make. Your example dict has nothing to with the code in your question. If you want an answer you need to **update your question** with a complete self contained example of what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL statement looks off, I think you want something like:

```
sql2='''insert into PERSONS (person_id , person_name) VALUES (%s, %s);'''
cursor.execute(sql2, (i.person_id, i.person_name))
```

Assuming the property names in `i` here.

Comment: "off" in what way? Can you mention what you changed?

Comment: @tdelaney I think because I'm trying to insert an object containing a dictionary. it is still an object so I need to be using proper parameter passing which is () instead of {}

Answer (score -1):

Your line

```
sql2 = '''insert into PERSONS(person_id , person_name) VALUES{};'''.format(i)
```

Should be fixed

```
sql2 = '''INSERT INTO PERSONS (person_id, person_name) VALUES (value1, value2, ...)'''.format(i)
```

Comment: What is the fix here? Is it just adding a space after VALUES? `insert into` is case insensitive and generally you want to keep the semicolon at the end (some dbs care).

Comment: I tried to do exactly that but It gives me an error psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn  saying that the columns does not exist even if these columns DOES exists in my data table